# Match word pattern in bash script

Tags: regex, string, bash, shell

I have a lot of pdf files that have this pattern: 
"TN_[0-9]{6}.pdf" and I need to check that a file has this pattern. I've tried this:

```
pattern = "TN_[0-9]{6}.pdf"

for file in *.pdf
do
  if [[ "$file" =~ $pattern ]];
  then

  done
```

but it gives me

> [[: not found

Comment: From this error message, I would conclude that you are not running bash.

Comment: yes but I passed to bash after

Comment: Can you verify, that you were running bash? Can you also post the FULL error message line? If it is bash, the error message would in this case also say 'bash'.

Comment: I got the error when I ran the script with sh, after I have used bash

Comment: Well, of course you get an error when you are using a bash construct and don't run it under bash! Why then do you put "bash" as a tag of your posting if the question does not apply to bash?

Comment: Sorry, because I'd understood that it wasn't bash after your first comment, I didn't know that I was using a only bash constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am getting your question correctly you need to print file names or get files whose name is `TN_[0-6] 6 times.pdf` you could try following then.

```
ls -ltr TN_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].pdf
OR
ls TN_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].pdf
```

OR use:

```
ls -1 TN* | grep -E 'TN_[0-9]{6}.pdf'
```

Somehow `{6}` is not working with `ls` command.

Comment: Why is repeating [0-9] six times different than using {6} ?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness, I tried that but it is NOT working for my box, checking on that only, will post it.

Comment: I am asking out of curiosity, I would be surprised if the two patterns were different in bash though.

Comment: actually i've tried this "for file in TN_[0-9]{6}.pdf" and didn't work while TN_[0-9]six time work

Comment: @UnbearableLightness shell globs are not the same as regex. You can't use constructs like `{6}` (at least in `bash` as far as I know).

Answer (score 2):

Modify `pattern = "TN_[0-9]{6}.pdf"` to `pattern="TN_[0-9]{6}.pdf"`. Otherwise pattern will be interpreted as command.